# MacBook Pro 2016 Touch Bar usage in Windows 10 Boot Camp

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, touch-bar

Has anybody already installed Windows 10 and verified the workings of the Touch Bar with the normal function keys (+ ESC) as promised [here](http://www.macrumors.com/2016/10/28/using-touch-bar-with-boot-camp-windows/)?

> **Question from Abraham:** Craig, am I correct in assuming that the Touch Bar becomes a row of visual function keys when using Windows with Boot Camp?
>
> **Federighi's answer**: You are indeed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally haven't had the chance to try so.
But this video from 9to5 mac shows the functionality of the touchbar in windows via bootcamp.
[tips and tricks for the touchbar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aU2eqKO-Fz4&ab_channel=9to5Mac)
Windows is mentioned at 6:50
[image]
As you can see, the brightness and volume keys are available.
And here is a picture of my new macbook in bootcamp showing the functionality of the fn button:
[image: fn key in bootcamp]

Comment: Almost made me 100% confident. The narrotor says so but doesnt actually show it (function keys displayed in the Touch Bar)...

Comment: well I do receive my new mbp with touch bar on the 23th and I intend to install bootcamp on it so I can show you that it really is true then :)

Comment: That would be very nice!

Comment: Received the MBP today?

Comment: Yes I did! And the guy in the video is telling the truth, I will post a picture in a few hours showing the function keys

Comment: Nice Dennis! From Netherlands by the way? Hopefully I will find some time this weekend to do the ordering :()